# Pass a table as condition with where clause in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table t:

```
t:([] sym:`GOOG`AMZN; px:10 20; vol:100 200);
```

Is it possible to pass a sub-table as a where clause condition to the table?
Below query throws type error:

```
select from t where ([] sym:enlist `GOOG; px:enlist 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
q)select from t where([]sym;px) in ([] sym:enlist `GOOG; px:enlist 10)
sym  px vol
-----------
GOOG 10 100
```

Update: however, if `t` is large this should be much faster:

```
q)([] sym:enlist `GOOG; px:enlist 10)#2!t
sym  px| vol
-------| ---
GOOG 10| 100
```